# Question regarding IDL

Tags: anchor, idl

Guys I am trying to learn about Coding on Solana & I have a question that, if there is no IDL of a program or the IDL is not updated of a program then how do we get the account data & eventually form an IDL file ourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solana Programs need to define their own data structure for serialization/deserialzation. So, if the program is not opens source, that is, you do not know the layout/schema of the account or instructions, you will be not able to decode it.

If you are the program owner, which means you have access to the object layouts, in which case, you can decode like below:

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/borsh like this

> const buffer = myAccount.data;
>
> const schema = new Map([[Test, { kind: 'struct', fields: [['x', 'u8'],
> ['y', 'u64'], ['z', 'string'], ['q', [3]]] }]]);
>
> const newValue = borsh.deserialize(schema, Test, buffer);

If you do not have access to the layout/schema of the account and instructions you need to first gain access to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to derive an IDL from a non-anchor program then there is a tool called shank [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/shank) and if you are looking for IDL for some of the existing Solana programs which are not written in anchor but are used a lot in the ecosystem then you can take a look at this repo [here](https://github.com/acheroncrypto/native-to-anchor)